# timezone abbreviation datetimepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, timezone, datetimepicker

i am trying create a datetimepicker that has to display date something like below had used trntrichardson plugin to use datetimepicker.

Tue, 2 Apr 2013 12:00 AM IST

i had the following code in which i am storing the UTC time as value and displaying local time in the text..but i am not able to add the local timezone abbreviation like IST, CST etc., as shown in above date.

plz is there any work around to get that done..i am using moment plugin for converting utc and local times.

```
_createDateTime: function () {
            var min = this.element.attr("data-minRelDate"),
                max = this.element.attr("data-maxRelDate");

            this._Input = $("<input>")
                .addClass("datetime")
                .datetimepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 2,
                    minDate: min,
                    maxDate: max,                    
                    dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_1123,
                    hourGrid: 2,
                    minuteGrid: 5,
                    timeFormat: "hh:mm TT z",
                    showTimeZone: true,                        
                    onSelect: $.proxy(this._change, this)         
                })                
                .appendTo(this._Wrapper);

_change: function(){
            var val = this._Input.datepicker("getDate");
            //var test = moment(val).format();

            //UTC to store value in server.
            this.element
                .attr("data-datetime", moment.utc(val)
                .format("LLLL"));

            //LocalTime To display.            
            this._Input.datepicker("setDate", new Date(moment(val).format("LLLL")));        
        }
```

i had converted in to local time and gave the datetimepicker taht date , what all i need to do is just have to add timezone abbreviation in the date string....any work around plz.....

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to produce a time-picker with a dropdown containing time zone abbreviations?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/162

follow the link its not possible to get that work across the browsers, so have to stick to chrome if u wanna use the functions like Data.Prototype.Tostring